# How to extend a Loss Function Pytorch

Tags: python, deep-learning, mathematical-optimization, pytorch, loss-function

I would like to create my own custom Loss function as a weighted combination of 3 Loss Function, something similar to:

```
criterion = torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss(out1, lbl1) + \
            torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss(out2, lbl2) + \
            torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss(out3, lbl3)
```

I am doing it to address a multi-class multi-label classification problem.
Does it make sense? How to implement correctly such Loss Function in Pytorch?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your way of approaching the problem seems correct but there's a typo in your code. Here's a fix for that:

```
loss1 = torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss()(out1, lbl1)
loss2 = torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss()(out2, lbl2) 
loss3 = torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss()(out3, lbl3)

final_loss = loss1 + loss2 + loss3
```

Then you can call `.backward` on `final_loss` which should then compute the gradients and backpropagate them.

Also, it's possible to *weight* each of the component losses where the *weights* are itself *learned* during the training process.

You can refer the discussions of [combine-multiple-criterions-to-a-loss-function](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/how-to-combine-multiple-criterions-to-a-loss-function/348/3) for more information.